# Changing programatic uiscrollview to IB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

got a bit of a small problem here. I've been following this tutorial which creates an automatic scrolling slideshow using uiscrollview. This piece of code is used in my viewdidload -

```
UIScrollView *scr=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 180)];
scr.tag = 1;
scr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
[self.view addSubview:scr];
[self setupScrollView:scr];
UIPageControl *pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 60)];
[pgCtr setTag:12];
pgCtr.numberOfPages=10;
pgCtr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
[self.view addSubview:pgCtr];
```

As you can see a small uiscrollview is created programatically which is 320x180. It works perfectly except for the fact that my UI has another uiscrollview which takes up the whole ui, which is around 320x700. I need to embed this programatically created scrollview into it, any ideas? Or alternatively I need to create my own scrollview using storyboards and link it across using code, but have no idea how I would go about this.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed the scroll view inside the scroll view not the main view

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:scr];
```